# Domain name validator for Django

Tags: django

Since there is no progress on this ticket, I am searching for a library which provides DomainNameValidator or a DomainNameField for Django.

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18119

Required features:

- Works with Django 2.2
- open source
- ensures that no invalid hostname gets entered.
- Pure syntax check is enough. No active DNS-querying is wanted.